# Connect Gear 2 to Tizen SDK and get Data From Sensor

Tags: javascript, android, android-sensors, tizen-wearable-sdk

i'm searching a way to develop an application that can collect data from sensor embedded in Samsung Gear 2 lite, to do this i thinked to use the Android API but after some searching i found that gear 2 not supporting Android, so it support only tizen API, so i installed the Tizen SDK and i try to run the application directly in Gear 2 via a us cable, but when i try it the emulator say that i must certificate the device before running apps, but do what written in help, i got the necessaries files but in the last it say that the certification is failed cause of failure to find the path the some key...

so firstly is there anyone who know how to solve this problem?

in other side, i searched for a way to run the android apps in gear 2 directly from emulator or phone (S4) , hope that you can tell me a solution to do this without changing the device or developing with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in certification, i succeed to install certification, the problem was related to the steps to follow, i tried the right sequence of steps, and i got the perfect result, i can for now install Tizen application in gear directly or from sumsung galaxy with the application Samsung Gear application, i embedded the gwt file in the android project and when the android apps is installed, the gear application will be installed directly in Gear watch, so i havn't to use usb cable  to install the gear application. 
Thank for your suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

get the certificate needed for you to work with the device you have, this is a decent doc with step on howto:
http://electrozoic.com/beginning-tizen-gear-s/

Comment: You should add content from your link here, in case it ever goes down. Link-only answers are discouraged on SO. But welcome :)